# How set rule in .htaccess when QUERY ?random_letters_numbers=abracadabra

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My site under attack in logs i have random query on main page:

```
IP - - [DATE] "GET /?random_letters_numbers=abracadabra HTTP/1.1"
```

How i can block this query **only main page** and don't block utm_tags.

I set rule .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?).{1,10}=.*$
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

**but this code work in utm tags too block it.**

```
?utm_source=wnc_10030322&utm_medium=gamma&utm_campaign=wnc_10030322&utm_content=test
```

Logs:

```
"GET /?CEosEj=BTC5fK HTTP/1.1"
"GET /?TZJWAv=fSbz0W HTTP/1.1"
"GET /?rLp5Fy=mH3Sro HTTP/1.1"

IP - - [02/Aug/2022:10:37:53 +0300] "GET /?vKcMMM=ZtMbVV HTTP/1.1" 200 299 "mydomain" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"
IP - - [02/Aug/2022:10:37:53 +0300] "GET /?sQv4E1=faF26B HTTP/1.1" 200 299 "mydomain" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G970F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.53 Mobile Safari/537.36 OPR/63.3.3216.58675"
IP - - [02/Aug/2022:10:37:53 +0300] "GET /?1cPe0W=cN2HQC HTTP/1.1" 200 299 "mydomain" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
IP - - [02/Aug/2022:10:37:53 +0300] "GET /?fWF6uH=HQtAfD HTTP/1.1" 200 299 "mydomain" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/4.3"
IP - - [02/Aug/2022:10:37:53 +0300] "GET /?3YPAHg=EsvwFq HTTP/1.1" 200 299 "mydomain" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Good that you have posted your efforts and log. Could you please also do add sample links which you want to block in your question; that will help us more to understand question more clearly.

Comment: THX. I add more info in post.

Answer (score 3):

> How i can block this query only main page and don't block utm_tags.

You can use this rule;

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(?!(v|utm_[^=]+)=)[^=]+= [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
```

Here:

- `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(?!(v|utm_[^=]+)=)[^=]+=`: Makes sure query string is not `utm_...=...` or `v=...`
- `RewriteRule ^$`: Matches landing page only
- `[F]`: Sends back http status 403 (forbidden) to clients

[Here is RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oPkSjE/1)

Comment: I have random query in log - example:
 "GET /?CEosEj=BTC5fK HTTP/1.1"
 "GET /?TZJWAv=fSbz0W HTTP/1.1"

Comment: @CB9TOIIIA, Could you please do update your question with these provided samples, its always advised to update question, thank you.

Comment: I update topic (add examples in logs)

Comment: Is not utm_tags, it's utm_source / utm_content and etc. 

How i can block only main page query /?random_letters=random_letters_too

Comment: What are all query parameters that you want to allow? Do they all start with `utm_` ?

Comment: I think all start utm tags, but my rule work all site, not only main page.

Comment: Thanks, but my rule does not only work on the main page - it also affects the versioning of stylesheets and scripts ?v=17.3 and so on. How can a rule only start when /?randomness=randomness

Comment: `RewriteRule ^$` **will match only landing page**. I have already handled any unknown `/?randomness=randomness` situation. Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 404 URLs you get.

Comment: Please try my updated code.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following htaccess rules. These rules will check if a query string is NOT exactly matching value: `utm_source=wnc_10030322&utm_medium=gamma&utm_campaign=wnc_10030322&utm_content=test` then block that url.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/b6XgBX/1) for used regex in htaccess rules.

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^utm_source=wnc_[^&]*&utm_medium=[^&]*&utm_campaign=wnc_[^&]*&utm_content=\S+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^v=[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [F]
```

Comment: THX. But links not always contain all utm tags.

Comment: @CB9TOIIIA, I have updated rules/regex as per your latest edit, please do check it once.

Comment: Thanks, but my rule does not only work on the main page - it also affects the versioning of stylesheets and scripts ?v=17.3 and so on. How can a rule only start when /?randomness=randomness

Comment: @CB9TOIIIA, I have added one more condition to rules now, please do check them and let me know then how it goes.

Comment: @CB9TOIIIA, Just refresh this page before you copy the rules please.

Comment: Thank you, it's better, but I'll probably find something else that is blocked. Is there a homepage-only rule?

Comment: @CB9TOIIIA, `s there a homepage-only rule?` could you please elaborate more on this one with sample urls, hank you.

Comment: mysite.local/?Gyp5Wv=6jSo1h - block only main page this query (?uCf0ZN=b770Ay / ?random=abracadabra)

Comment: @CB9TOIIIA, ok, I have edited the rules now. Kindly do check it once and confirm how it goes.

Comment: now skip query ?Gyp5Wv=6jSo1h (end v= and start rules v=) / but this query bad. can something be done in this case?

Comment: This will also block if query string starts with `utm_medium=`. We should not assume ordering of query parameters IMO

Comment: @CB9TOIIIA, as anubhava sir mentioned in previous comment, do you have exact query string `utm_source=wnc_10030322&utm_medium=gamma&utm_campaign=wnc_10030322&utm_content=test`? OR you want to look for string `utm` only?

Comment: @CB9TOIIIA, Also for your previous comment `(end v= and start rules v=) ` you want to block query string starts with v= and ends with v=?